# Which version of sqoop is compatible with hadoop 3.0

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

When running `sqoop version`, getting this error:

> hadoopusr@houssein:~$ sqoop version
>   Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
>   Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
>
> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
>   Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
>
> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>
> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
>
> /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2326: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: bad substitution
>   /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2421: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: bad substitution
>   2019-02-24 04:43:16,533 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
>   Sqoop 1.4.7
>   git commit id 2328971411f57f0cb683dfb79d19d4d19d185dd8
>   Compiled by maugli on Thu Dec 21 15:59:58 STD 2017`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

First, change the version of Hadoop to 2.6.x.

The environment warnings say that you need put each dependency in the correspondent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the below:

`SQOOP_HOME` and other params are configured in .profile

`the HADOOP_COMMON_HOME & HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` setup are already done in `$SQOOP_HOME/conf path.`

I too faced a similar issue but it resolved after i added the mysql connectors

I downloaded the below from the link given below, the file mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.tar.gz (you can google and download it from a different link as well)

[Link to download][1]

**Steps to configure the mysql connector.**

Once the mysql-connector-java gz package is downloaded, Run the below commands to unzip it:

```
tar -xvf mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.tar.gz

mv mysql-connector-java-8.0.15/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar /$SQOOP_HOME/lib
```

Finally, to verify the installation, run:

**sqoop version**

This will output version about sqoop

Hope this helps!!